# Json parse through ansible

Tags: json, ansible

I have below json

```
    "edge_router_uuid.stdout": {
        "buildInfo": {
            "buildNumber": "20004",
            "buildTimestamp": "1539995399724",
        },
        "isUp": true,
        "pod": "gateway",
        "reachable": true,
        "region": "dc-1",
        "tags": {
        ........
```

Actually it is a big json and I am showing above is just a part of it. I need to use the "debug" in ansible to get the variable values for region and reachable values. When I am trying the below

```
  - debug:
      var: edge_router_uuid.stdout.region
```

getting below error.

```
ok: [10.10.10.10] => {
    "edge_router_uuid.stdout.region": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON syntax is wrong. The problem is "," behind the last value

```
    "buildInfo": {
        "buildNumber": "20004",
        "buildTimestamp": "1539995399724",
    }
```

Correct syntax is

```
    "buildInfo": {
        "buildNumber": "20004",
        "buildTimestamp": "1539995399724"
    }
```

Comment: Actually it is a big json and I am showing above is just a part of it

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to get it as below

```
- set_fact:
    response_dict: "{{ edge_router_uuid.stdout }}"
```

I ended up with a dictionary named response_dict. Then I am able to get the region value like this:

```
- debug:
    var: response_dict.region
```